# Launch lightning Component from Related List Button?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I'm just coming around to learning more about developing in lightning. still going through trailheads and whatnot. However, I can't seem to find how to do a few things.

1. How can I override the new button on a related list in lightning?
2. If I can't override, how can I add new buttons there and remove the standard new button
3. How can I launch a lightning component from a relatedlist button? (I see I can still launch a visualforce page but nothing on lightning components)

Is there a trailhead on any of these topics, perhaps?

Comment: Does it not suffice to embed that component in `Visualforce`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson It does. Wanted to make sure there isn't a better/ preferred way to do it. Basically just want to make sure I'm following best practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, your best bet here is still to use `Visualforce` and just [surface lightning through that page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm).

```
<apex:page standardController="ChildObject__c" recordSetVar="children">
    <!-- include lightning here -->
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a URL link to a lightning app page to achieve this [as described here](https://salesforcediaries.com/2020/10/06/open-lightning-component-from-url-button-in-lightning/):

Create and activate a lightning app page that includes your component. URL is then /lightning/n/My_App_Page

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot override a standard New button on the Related List rather you can create new Custom button and name it as New.
2. In the page layout of that particular object -- go to related list
   you can uncheck the standard button and can add new custom buttons
3. We can create new record by various ways using URL HACK TECHNIQUES

1. Create a new record

`/lightning/o/ObjectName/new?recordTypeId={}`

2. To skip the Record Type Selection

`/lightning/o/Account/new?RecordType.Name='RecordTypeName'&defaultFieldValues=AccountId__c={!Account.Id}`

3. To call Aura component and Use these variable parameters by pageReference

`/lightning/cmp/c__auraName?c__id={!ObjectName.Id}&c__Object=ObjectName&c__AccountId={!Account.Id}`

4. To call LWC

`/lightning/n/MYLWC`

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge still Visualforce embedded with Lightning component is the only option

Comment: This answer is basically an exact duplicate of that which is already accepted.